# Google Chrome crashes on Windows 8.1

Tags: google-chrome, crash

I have Asus X200MA notebook with Windows 8.1 64 Bit. Google Chrome works for a few instances initially after installation and then simply fails to load subsequently.

Upon starting chrome, windows flashes a message box 'Google Chrome has stopped working, windows is searching for solution to problem' and  eventually I have no option but to close the message box and chrome exits.  I have tried system restore as well as re-installation of chrome (Including offline setup) however the story repeats. I have no clue why it keeps crashing. I even tried Reset Windows 8.1 by wiping the OS drive and re-installing chrome, still eventually it crashes after a few instances.

On this forum similar issues have been reported and I have even tried the suggested solutions like delete AppData..\default folder and also start chrome with --disable-sync-bookmarks  commandline but it did not work in my case.

If anyone knows a solution, please help.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you logged into a Google account when you install Chrome? If so, try uninstalling then reinstalling and not logging into an account. See if that causes a different. And what about running in incognito mode from the beginning?

Comment: Are you using the Comodo Firewall? If so you need to update the firewall. I had the same problem on Windows 7 and tried all the things you did then found the following link. Fixed by firewall update. See https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/IWaiZtj818g

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Yes I have installed Comodo Internet Security and related suggestion worked. I updated Comodo and added chrome.exe under Firewall --> Defense+ --> HIPS --> HIPS Settings --> Detect shellcode injection [Exclusions]. The issue is resolved. Thanks a lot @DavidPostill.  You may like to post it under Answer section so that I shall accept it as well.

Comment: @pat2015 I'm happy I could solve your problem. Answer added ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Google Chrome crashes on Windows 8.1

This is a known problem with the latest version of Chrome when using [Comodo Firewall](https://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/firewall.php).

Updating Comodo to the lastest version as of yesterday will fix the issue (confirmed as I had the same problem on Windows 7).

Note:

- There is another Comodo update available today.

There is also a workaround:

> This is a currently known problem with Comodo Internet Security that
>   causes the crash in Chrome 45:
>
> https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=527496  -  Comodo
>   antivirus hooks break Chrome 45 (crash in "guard32.dll" module)
>
> Suggested workaround:  In Comodo CIS, go to Defense+ --> HIPS --> HIPS
>   Settings --> Detect shellcode injection [Exclusions], and then add
>   chrome.exe to the exclusion list.

...

> Comodo just prompted me to install update 8.2.0.4703, after install I now have a HIPS exclusion for "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application*"

Source [Chrome Crashes With Comodo Firewall](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/IWaiZtj818g)